# Mostrar correctamente tildes y 'ñ'

Tags: php, html

Estoy diseñando una página web con `php` y framework w3. No utilizo base de datos y el texto que quiero mostrar en pantalla esta escrito directamente en el `html`.

Estoy utilizando codificación ISO-8859-1 en todas las páginas.

```
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>
```

Ejemplo:

```
      <p class="w3-justify"> La clínica es un centro de abordaje integral del desarrollo del lactante, el niño, el adolescente y el adulto,
            con 12 años de trayectoria. Su filosofía de trabajo se basa en una atención interdisciplinaria a través de los distintos
            profesionales que la integran, aportando desde cada especialidad estrategias para comprender y abordar la problemática en
            juego.
            Al mismo tiempo se realiza la coordinación con la familia (brindándole apoyo y orientación), institución educativa
            y otros profesionales de la salud vinculados.
        </p>
```

Salida:

La clÃ­nica es un centro de abordaje integral del desarrollo del lactante, el niÃ±o, el adolescente y el adulto, con 12 aÃ±os de trayectoria. Su filosofÃ­a de trabajo se basa en una atenciÃ³n interdisciplinaria a travÃ©s de los distintos profesionales que la integran, aportando desde cada especialidad estrategias para comprender y abordar la problemÃ¡tica en juego. Al mismo tiempo se realiza la coordinaciÃ³n con la familia (brindÃ¡ndole apoyo y orientaciÃ³n), instituciÃ³n educativa y otros profesionales de la salud vinculados.

Probé utilizando utf-8 pero me da el mismo resultado.

Comment: 1. Asegúrate de que la codificación del editor donde escribiste el texto es utf-8. 2. Coloca en el header: `<meta charset="utf-8">` 3. Asegúrate de que **no hay ningún otro header por ahí deambulante** que cambia el charset.

Comment: @A.Cedano no hay forma, todos los archivos con charset utf-8 y estoy utilizando visual studio code en esa codificación

Comment: En este articulo hay contenido que creo te puede ser útil :
https://www.gestiweb.com/?q=content/problemas-html-acentos-y-e%C3%B1es-charset-utf-8-iso-8859-1.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir la URL a la página oficial del framework que mencionas?

Comment: @Orici https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp

Answer (score 2):

Usa siempre UTF-8:

> 1. En la codificación de los ficheros.
> 2. En tu HTML. Para HTML5 usa `<meta charset="utf-8">` en el header.

Usa funciones multibyte de PHP si tuvieras que hacer alguna operación sobre strings. http://php.net/manual/es/ref.mbstring.php. Y con respecto a éste último punto, si usas un **framework PHP**, ¿puede ser que use una compilación o cache? que no use estas funciones (más lentas) y por eso tengas esos resultados. Averigua si tiene alguna configuración para el idioma y que no este seleccionado inglés.

Si usas un **framework CSS** el problema seguramente vendrá con la codificación del fichero. Puedes cambiarle la codificación al fichero que falla pero aun así no suele funcionar. Si tu editor te lo permite, configuralo para que genere siempre ficheros utf8, crea un nuevo archivo, copia y pega el contenido de alguno de los ficheros que te esta dando errores en el nuevo y reemplaza con este al antiguo. Comprueba si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas ese mismo problema lo tuve, para solucionarlo puedes poner el `codigo` saludos espero te ayude

```
á -> &aacute;
é -> &eacute;
í -> &iacute;
ó -> &oacute;
ú -> &uacute;
ñ -> &ntilde;
```

Answer (score -1):

Solo necesitas de cambiar esto:

> meta charset="ISO-8859-1"

por esto:

> meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/

Comment: Tampoco cambia nada con utf-8

Comment: He cambiado la respuesta, prueba a hacerlo como lo he puesto ahora

Comment: Tampoco, borre cache y recargue y reinicie el modulo apache de xampp pero nada